Unable to generate link preview for webpages of our website
I've created a react SPA. But when I share the link, it neither generates the link preview nor the description & title. I used meta tags from metatags.io for preview but it didn't work. This website is deployed at Vercel
In my index.html file, I added these meta tags:
<title>My website</title>
<meta name="title" content="My website" />
<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit" />

<!-- Open Graph / Facebook -->
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.mywebsite.io/" />
<meta property="og:title" content="My website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit" />
<meta property="og:image" content="./favicon.png" />


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Use react-helmet attach it to your component and add those OG tags wrapping in react-helmet component, I hope it solves your problem
